# How do I make my web-page responsive in Figma?

Tags: web, constraints, responsive, figma

I have just started learning Web-Design. I have bought online courses from Udemy and I am on the stage where I have to create responsive page in figma.

Guys I am sure that responsive page is very important whenever you are designing the web-page. Therefore I would really appreciate if you would help me out I am sure some of you have faced similar problem before.

I have designed Home page for a company and whenever I try to minimise the size of it, what happens is that the header that I have starts to move alongside with the new size that I have applied, So it works as it's supposed to work, But the frame of the text that I have written there, is not responsive.
I have applied the measures for constraints I set It up with every possible way that I could but it just doesn't work, It is not responsive.

If you have any solutions please reply I would really appreciate it :)

I have tried to work with constraints, I have set up the text as " fixed " , " Hugged " but it doesn't seem to work.
I have also watched that part on my online course for a thousand time but I couldn't find the solution. And of course YouTube videos and every one of them says to apply this constraints, But I guess I didn't understand some part of it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo1d1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting your text layer to constraints horizontal left-right, should make it stay the same distance to either left or right side as you're changing the size of the window.

Make sure that the layer is in the correct frame and not just in the same position as the frame.